# How to add and get Header values in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I need to create a POST method in WebApi so I can send data from application to WebApi method. I'm not able to get header value.

Here I have added header values in the application:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    // Set the header so it knows we are sending JSON.
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

    client.Headers.Add("Custom", "sample");
    // Make the request
    var response = client.UploadString(url, jsonObj);
}
```

Following the WebApi post method:

```
public string Postsam([FromBody]object jsonData)
{
    HttpRequestMessage re = new HttpRequestMessage();
    var headers = re.Headers;

    if (headers.Contains("Custom"))
    {
       string token = headers.GetValues("Custom").First();
    }
}
```

What is the correct method for getting header values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

On the Web API side, simply use Request object instead of creating new HttpRequestMessage

```
var re = Request;
var headers = re.Headers;

if (headers.Contains("Custom"))
{
    string token = headers.GetValues("Custom").First();
}

return null;
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: Can you not use `string token = headers.GetValues("Custom").FirstOrDefault();`?
Edit: Just noticed you were matching original Qs style.

Comment: Answering my own Q: No. The `headers.GetValues("somethingNotFound")` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Do I use `beforeSend` in JQuery ajax to send the header?

Comment: Perfect... I used the `beforeSend` and it worked. Awesome :) +1

Comment: what is the type of the Request variable and can I access it inside the controller method ? I am using web api 2. What namespace do I need to import?

Comment: @lohiarahul I believe that is the Fetch API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Comment: "if (headers.Contains("Custom"))" not worked. So, I have added like, "if (headers.AllKeys.Contains("Custom"))".

Answer (score 27):

Suppose we have a API Controller 
ProductsController : ApiController

There is a Get function which returns some value and expects some input header (for eg. UserName & Password)

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers = this.Request.Headers;
    string token = string.Empty;
    string pwd = string.Empty;
    if (headers.Contains("username"))
    {
        token = headers.GetValues("username").First();
    }
    if (headers.Contains("password"))
    {
        pwd = headers.GetValues("password").First();
    }
    //code to authenticate and return some thing
    if (!Authenticated(token, pwd)
        return Unauthorized();
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(product);
}
```

Now we can send the request from page using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/products/10',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { 'username': 'test','password':'123' },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function (result) {
        alert('Error: ' + result);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone ...

Answer (score 23):

As someone already pointed out how to do this with .Net Core, if your header contains a "-" or some other character .Net disallows, you can do something like:

```
public string Test([FromHeader]string host, [FromHeader(Name = "Content-Type")] string contentType)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was searching for !

Answer (score 15):

Another way using a the TryGetValues method.

```
public string Postsam([FromBody]object jsonData)
{
    IEnumerable<string> headerValues;

    if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Custom", out headerValues))
    {
        string token = headerValues.First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For .NET Core:

```
string Token = Request.Headers["Custom"];
```

Or

```
var re = Request;
var headers = re.Headers;
string token = string.Empty;
StringValues x = default(StringValues);
if (headers.ContainsKey("Custom"))
{
   var m = headers.TryGetValue("Custom", out x);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In case someone is using ASP.NET Core for model binding,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

There's is built in support for retrieving values from the header using the [FromHeader] attribute

```
public string Test([FromHeader]string Host, [FromHeader]string Content-Type )
{
     return $"Host: {Host} Content-Type: {Content-Type}";
}
```

Comment: `Content-Type` is not a valid C# identifier

Comment: I am sending the header value as x-publisher, how should I handle it.

Answer (score 6):

try these line of codes working in my case:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>();
this.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out values);
```

Answer (score 4):

For WEB API 2.0:

I had to use `Request.Content.Headers` instead of  `Request.Headers`

and then i declared an extestion as below

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Returns an individual HTTP Header value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="headers"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetHeader(this HttpContentHeaders headers, string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> keys = null;
        if (!headers.TryGetValues(key, out keys))
            return defaultValue;

        return keys.First();
    }
```

And then i invoked it by this way.

```
  var headerValue = Request.Content.Headers.GetHeader("custom-header-key", "default-value");
```

I hope it might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
app.MapGet("/", ([FromHeader(Name = "User-Agent")] string data) =>
{
    return $"User agent header is: {data}";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple function to get a header value, with a "one-liner" variant using TryGetValue:

```
private string GetHeaderValue(string key) =>
    Request.Headers.TryGetValue(key, out var value)
        ? value.First()
        : null;

var headerValue = GetHeaderValue("Custom");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the HttpRequestMessage from the current OperationContext. Using OperationContext you can do it like so

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;

HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = messageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

string customHeaderValue = requestProperty.Headers["Custom"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For .net Core in GET method, you can do like this:

```
 StringValues value1;
 string DeviceId = string.Empty;

  if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("param1", out value1))
      {
                DeviceId = value1.FirstOrDefault();
      }
```