# ASP.NET 5 MVC6 Web API Post header and body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, angular, angular2-services

It seems I can post a json object in the body with no trouble and bind it via [FromBody].  I can also post the header and bind it with [FromHeader(Name=...)].  But I can't use them together.  Anyone know how or have another way of binding ether?

my Controller action method looks like this:

```
public JsonResult ProductQuery([FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")]string value, [FromBody] Product product)
```

When I do this I get the header in value but I don't get the body, I get a null in product

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One way would be : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21405101/1129995

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/31460183/3645004

Comment: Thanks for the references.  There is no problem with bring in the header and body as I show.  The problem is Angular 2 sends the wrong content type when sending header info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below gave me the best hint but his solution was jQuery.

There is no problem with bringing in the header and body as I show. The problem is Angular 2 sends the wrong content type when sending header info. I had to do this in angular 2 on the client side. Note the 'Content-Type' line:

```
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post('/api/orderProdListQuery', JSON.stringify(query), { headers: headers })
```

[how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)