# Accessing Request/Response Headers C#

Tags: c#, http, networking

I am currently trying to access Request/Response Headers using C# as well as accessing the request/response body from a website that has a username/password login. I believe I've gotten it to the point of logging in, its mostly just accessing the data.

So first I open up an `HttpWebRequest` to the login page and submit my credentials. Then I create a `webclient` with a proxy to login to the remote server and give it credentials as well. Then I tried to download the data however all I get is the response body but I need the request body and request header from the server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace ScrapeTest
 {
    class Program{

        static void Main(string[] args){
            HttpWebRequest baseRequest = WebRequest.Create("remoteserver") as HttpWebRequest;
            baseRequest.Timeout = 50000;
            baseRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 7;
            baseRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            HttpWebResponse baseResponse = baseRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("proxyServer",true);
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxyUsername", "proxyPassword");
            proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
            client.Proxy = proxy;
            string head = client.Headers.ToString();
            NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
            byte[] res = client.UploadValues("otherPage", "GET", data);
            string resString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res);
            Console.WriteLine(resString);
            byte[] info = client.DownloadData("otherPage");
            string responseString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(info);
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            client.Dispose();
            baseResponse.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add and get Header values in WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404734/how-to-add-and-get-header-values-in-webapi)

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a form in C#, I assume, or it may be easier if utilizing ASP.NET.

Here's a simple example from another SO on how to access form data:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string userName, password;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtUserName"]))
{
  userName = nvc["txtUserName"];
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtPassword"]))
{
  password = nvc["txtPassword"];
}
```

Here's more info from Microsoft about the Form class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx

However if you provide more details we can provide you a better answer.

Comment: I am currently not using a form. So first I open up an HttpWebRequest to the login page and submit my credentials. Then I create a webclient with a proxy to login to the remote server and give it credentials as well. Then I tried to download the data however all I get is the response body but I need the request body and request header from the server

Comment: Ok, I see the new code.  Potentially you are looking for the HttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader method, since using HttpWebResponse class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponseheader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think you need the request body / header, since YOU are making the request.. so you have all that there.  But you can obtain the Response body (like you are) and the headers w/ that method

Comment: Let me explain my problem a bit further. So I have a script that runs separate from this code that already works and what it does is it scrapes data for a project and takes it and does some data analysis on an excel spreadsheet. The problem is that as of now I have to manually input two fields and the session ID in order to make this script work cause it gathers data from the website which is in my current code.

Comment: This new code is meant to automate that process so I don't have to manually go in and change it because the website sometimes will refresh the two fields and session ID when there is an error or the server goes down. So in order to do that I need the request header and body because it is generated by my server and now me directly

Comment: Ah ok - we recently had to do this as well - an API endpoint was sending it's version in it's headers, so we had to check if the version was the one we requested.  Anyway, like the duplicate comment person said - you can easily get this from the Headers property of the HttpWebResponse class your already using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers(v=vs.110).aspx