# Convert the request header to json string c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am sending the request headers via postman, Now I want to convert the request header into a json string so that I can Deserailze it into my below-mentioned object for headers, How could I do it?[Refer for request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUIdF.png)

```
public class AcceptPaymentRequestHeader
{
    [JsonProperty("Content_Type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-VERIFY")]
    public string XVerify { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-REDIRECT-METHOD")]
    public string XRedirectMethod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-CALLBACK-URL")]
    public string XCallBackUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X-CALL-METHOD")]
    public string XCallMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package? It's a very common way to serialize to and from JSON in C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404734/how-to-add-and-get-header-values-in-webapi have a look this question.